# Generate 10 digit unique number on refresh

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and want to generate unique 10 digits number for my SKU Number. I tried using a date with IP address and got a unique value first time. But after a refresh or saving product data I still have that same SKU number. Any Help?? My code is:

```
    <?php
     if(!empty($_POST)) {
      .....my code......   
      }

      else{
       $stamp = date("Ymdhis");
       $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
       $sku = "$stamp-$ip";
       $sku = str_replace(".", "", "$sku");
       $sku = str_replace("-", "", "$sku");
       $sku = str_replace(":", "", "$sku");
       $sku = substr($sku, 0,10);
       }
       ?>
```

Comment: Well, with only 10 digits, there will be potential for collisions, unless you also check that the generated number already exist. But you should do this via random-function.

Comment: Using random function is not reccommended for storing data into database

Comment: Your stamp is already producing 14 digits, with IP it's over 20. Besides substr starting with stamp, 10 digits will always give same value on a given hour. I'd recommend you use time(); function. Does it have to be exact 10 digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick random-string-generator I wrote:

```
function generateRandomString($alpha = true, $nums = true, $usetime = false, $string = '', $length = 120) {
$alpha = ($alpha == true) ? 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' : '';
$nums = ($nums == true) ? '1234567890' : '';

if ($alpha == true || $nums == true || !empty($string)) {
    if ($alpha == true) {
        $alpha = $alpha;
        $alpha .= strtoupper($alpha);
    } 
}
$randomstring = '';
$totallength = $length;
    for ($na = 0; $na < $totallength; $na++) {
            $var = (bool)rand(0,1);
            if ($var == 1 && $alpha == true) {
                $randomstring .= $alpha[(rand() % mb_strlen($alpha))];
            } else {
                $randomstring .= $nums[(rand() % mb_strlen($nums))];
            }
    }
if ($usetime == true) {
    $randomstring = $randomstring.time();
}
return($randomstring);
} // end generateRandomString
```

You can use it like this for what you need:

```
$SKU = generateRandomString(false, true, false, '', 10);
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the date to create a 10 digit unique number? year (4) + month with leading zero (2) + day with leading zero (2) + seconds with leading zero (2) = 10 digits

```
<?php
echo date("Ymds");
?>
```

Comment: Is it possible to use only ("dhis") i.e day , hr ,  minutes, sec

Comment: `dhis` is only 8 digits; and has a relatively high probability of clashes each month

Comment: What does it matter if your only goal is to have a unique 10 digit number? also, with "h" you use a 12 hour format so you could have 4 hrs twice (at 04:00 and at 16:00) in a day and that's what you want to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

Yall overcomplicating.

Use an existing library like random_compat (This library can generate strong random numbers and cryptographically secure random numbers.).
https://github.com/ircmaxell/random_compat/blob/master/lib/random.php

Example (your case):

```
$random = new \PHP\Random(true);
echo $random->token(10, '0123456789');
```

Comment: How does that A) return only digits, and B) return a 10-digit string?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie I totally misread it thinking hex digits was what he wanted. My bad.

Comment: Granted, it works, but involves using an external lib. Seems like overkill (at least for the OPs case).

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Very much true, and I'm sure OP's case isn't really in need of cryptographically secure random numbers. However, someone trying to search for good ways to generate secure random numbers will benefit from my answer. (Which is what stackoverflow is all about!)

Answer (score 1):

you could use this `$sku = rand(1000000000,9999999999)` this php function will generate a random no. every time

Comment: @NathanDawson Actually it always creates random no. within the range not necessary that they are unique